# "not so different from you after all"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I'm trying to find an appropriate closing for an article. Would something like...

> If you're new to the school too, don't be shy and talk to people! Maybe they're **not so different from you after all**?

... make sense? Google doesn't give me any results for "so different from you after all", so I'm wondering if this structure works at all.

Comment: Your parse is slightly odd: not so different from you + after all. It is not a set phrase. It's just writing. Bear in mind, Google is not a writer.

Answer (score 1):

Given only what you have provided, *after all* is unnecessary:

> If you're new to the school too, don't be shy and talk to people! Maybe they're not so different from you?

Adding *after all* implies an assumption or expectation is, or may possibly be false. If the previous sentences established an assumption or expectation then it makes sense to include *after all*. Otherwise *after all* works best when the assumption is provided inline.

An example of a possibly false assumption is people who speak or dress differently will not have much in common with the listener. This could be phrased as follows:

> If you're new to the school too, don't be shy and talk to people! They may dress or speak differently from you, but maybe they're not so different after all?

Sidenote: The sentence structure provided is slightly unusual. The intent would be understood by a native speaker. However, taken literally, the structure implies the listener is being advised to avoid the act of talking to people when being shy.

Consider revising to:

> If you're new to the school too, don't be shy. Talk to people! Maybe they're not so different from you after all?

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, the phrase "not so different from you after all" does yield multiple results. Examples being:

[Zuckerman, E. B. (2006). Growing Up Different by Bonjenji (p. 222). iUniverse.](https://books.google.com/books?id=qR76UUcAlw0C&pg=PA222&dq=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3kN7jo-DdAhXLPI8KHcRpBuQQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&f=false)

> It's a shock, actually, to discover that others are **not so different from you after all**, that they have feelings, also, that they very rarely express, and then to get the return trip realization that [...]

[Arden, S. (2014). A Glorious Christmas (p. 4). HQN Books.](https://books.google.com/books?id=MA60BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3kN7jo-DdAhXLPI8KHcRpBuQQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&f=false)

> India shook her head and continued, “I guess I'm **not so different from you after all,”** India volunteered. “I'd convinced myself that happy-ever-after wasn't real, but I've been slapped in the face with it so many times in past months that I can't ... [...]

[O’Connor, J. (2008). Have Your Wedding Cake and Eat It, Too (p. 108). Thomas Nelson Publishers.](https://books.google.com/books?id=jCGSg5Q0fwsC&q=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&dq=%22so%20different%20from%20you%20after%20all%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3kN7jo-DdAhXLPI8KHcRpBuQQ6AEIRDAG)

> It turns out that the person you wanted to be **wasn't so different from you after all**. It's never quite the same, or you wouldn't write another poem, but it doesn't have to be that outrageously different. You find that out, but only after years and years ...

Comment: It is not a set phrase. It is after all used with not so different.